# How can I deploy a Firebase Function that runs if a file is uploaded to Firebase Storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy a Firebase Function that runs if an image is uploaded to a bucket named "upload".  However, when I try to deploy the function I am getting this error:

**Failed to configure trigger GCS Bucket: upload**

Here is some additional information:

My bucket is: gs://my-firestore-c379d.appspot.com/upload

Here is a sample of the code:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();

functions.storage.bucket('upload').object().onChange(event => {

exports.photoInfo = functions.storage.object().onChange(event => {
const fileBucket = object.bucket; // The Storage bucket that contains the file.
const filePath = object.name; // File path in the bucket.
const contentType = object.contentType; // File content type.
const resourceState = object.resourceState; // The resourceState is 'exists' or 'not_exists' (for file/folder deletions).
const metageneration = object.metageneration; // Number of times metadata has been generated. New objects have a value of 1.
const metadata = object.metadata;
const guestId = object.metadata['guestId'];

console.log('object:' + object);
console.log('fileBucket: ' + fileBucket);
console.log('filePath: ' + filePath);
console.log('contentType: ' + contentType);
console.log('resourceState: ' + resourceState);
console.log('metageneration: ' + metageneration);
console.log('metadata: ' + metadata);
console.log('guestId: ' + guestId);

return 0;

});
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
"name": "functions",
"description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
"scripts": {
  "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint .",
  "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
  "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
  "start": "npm run shell",
  "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
  "logs": "firebase functions:log"
 },
"dependencies": {
  "firebase-admin": "~5.8.1",
  "firebase-functions": "^0.8.1",
  "@google-cloud/storage": "^1.5.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "eslint": "^4.12.0",
  "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0"
},
"private": true
}
```

I did some research and found these two links, but I am still not able to remove that error:

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/66

https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat-web/issues/184#issuecomment-290914672

How can create a function that only listens to changes made in the "upload" bucket and remove that error?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a syntax error:

```
functions.storage.bucket('upload').object().onChange(event => {

exports.photoInfo = functions.storage.object().onChange(event => {
```

If you look at the [documentation for triggering Cloud Functions from Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events) it says:

> Use `functions.storage` to create a function that handles Cloud Storage events. Depending on whether you want to scope your function to a specific Cloud Storage bucket or use the default bucket, **use one of the following** (emphasis mine):
>
> - `functions.storage.object()` to listen for object changes on the default storage bucket.
> - `functions.storage.bucket('bucketName').object()` to listen for object changes on a specific bucket.

```
exports.generateThumbnail = functions.storage.object().onChange(event => {
  // ...
});
```

This means you shouldn't use both signatures in one function, but pick the one that matches your needs. Since you're trying to trigger on a specific bucket:

```
functions.storage.bucket('upload').object().onChange(event => {
  // ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Frank. I got a little bit confused. Now I understand that the listener is for the whole bucket. It is not possible to have a listener for only a specific folder within a bucket.

Answer (score 0):

... those two nested exports also look strange, somehow.

FireStore would also have an [OnCreate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) event trigger... the examples at [Cloud Storage Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events) also do not show any nested exports / nested install-able triggers. maybe log the bucket name in [exports.generateThumbnail](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/c4dd8aed8c11a64e2ddc610adb2c832246791f12/quickstarts/thumbnails/functions/index.js) ?

bucket [ACL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-bucket-acls) could also prevent installing the trigger.

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for your comment. Frank's reply helped me to solve the issue.